# Hide app android not working?

Tags: android, show-hide

After changing package name android Hide not working this is the code i am using for hiding the application from app drawer.

```
                ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName(
                        ConfigActivity.this.getPackageName(),
                        ConfigActivity.this.getPackageName()
                                + ".MainActivity");

                ConfigActivity.this
                        .getPackageManager()
                        .setComponentEnabledSetting(
                                componentToDisable,
                                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

is there any changes needed after changing package name?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the class is being recompiled after package change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably changed the package name of the application but not the package of the activity. The code above therefore references wrong activity.

To find the name of `MainActivity`, it is much better to use the activity's class object:

```
ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName(
                    ConfigActivity.this.getPackageName(),
                    MainActivity.class.getName());
```